# How to remove a project from the Gradle Tasks view or clean the view?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

Here is my Gradle Tasks view:

[image]

There is a `ThisProj` project which is not in the eclipse workspace but it is in the Gradle Tasks. The problem was that while the project was in the workspace it appeared twice in this view so I removed it from the workspace in attempt to import it so it will show only once.

If the project is in the workspace I get 2 "open" icon directories with the same name. If it is not I get 1 "closed" icon directories like above. None of the tasks can be executed - they are all grayed out. How do I clean this list or remove the project?

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt and

First:

run `gradle cleanEclipse` to clean the Eclipse configuration completely

Then
 `gradle eclipse` to rebuild the Eclipse configuration

This will clean the Gradle Tasks list

Comment: I didn't install gradle. I'm using the wrapper for everything. can I do it that way? now I get the error that gradle is not a recognizable command

Comment: You should be using gradlew instead of gradle, let me know if it doesn't work